# NextJS SSR Headers have no cookies

Tags: reactjs, next.js

On my development environment the following code works flawlessly, no issues, no bugs, worked. For some odd reason when I push to production it doesn't have any cookies, it has ctx.req.headers, but no cookie. I've used this code for many other projects so I'm completely dumbfounded on why this doesn't work.

```
  export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    try {
      const userRes = await fetch(process.env.SERVER + `/auth/user`, {
        headers: { cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie },
        credentials: 'include',
      });

      const userData = await userRes.json();
      if (!userData || userData.rank < 5) {
        ctx.res.setHeader('location', '/')
        ctx.res.statusCode = 302
        ctx.res.end()  
      }
  
      return {
        props: {},
      };
    } catch (e) {

        ctx.res.setHeader('location', '/')
        ctx.res.statusCode = 302
        ctx.res.end()  

      return {
        props: {},
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are the cookies present in the browser for your prod URL?

Comment: @juliomalves if you clicking the privacy and seeing cookies, then yes. I can fetch user data using hooks, I can see them present manually, it all works fine, except the serversideprops.

Answer (score 0):

try ctx.req.cookies,it wroks on next-12.0.10

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).